# WebScraper.io - cant scrape multiple pages because of URL

Tags: web-scraping, scrape

im trying to learn how to use WEBSCRAPER.IO so i can build a database using a webpage's data (For a project) - But when i try to do as the video shows me i cannot get the scrape to go through the pages because the URL is different to that of the video.

Video Example

www.webpage/products/laptops?page=[1-20]

The webpage i want to scan

www.webpage/products/laptops/page/2/

So how would i create the Start URL for webscraper to go through the 20 pages

when i try to use the example from the video it only scans 1 page of my chosen webpage

I have tried veriations like

```
www.webpage/products/laptops/page/page=[1-20]/

www.webpage/products/laptops/page=[1-20]/

www.webpage/products/laptops?page=[1-20]/
```

but none of them seem to work. Im stuck.

Could anybody provide my with any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide the URL so we can see what the structure is like?

Comment: www.4download.net

Comment: https://4download.net/software/windows/page/[1-5]/ is the correct format for that site